# Why does native SQL do not work?

Tags: java, hibernate

I use hibernate v4.2.7.Final

Table structure is :

```
  CREATE TABLE "OWNER"."TABLE" 
   (    
    "COL1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COL2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COL3" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COL4" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COL5" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) ;
```

Method code source :

```
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public List<?> getAllPropertyValues(String property) {
    logger.debug("finding all {} from TABLE", property);
    try {

// Set the session ...

      String query = String.format(
          "SELECT DISTINCT t.%s, t.col2 FROM TABLE t ORDER BY t.col2",
          property.toUpperCase());
      logger.debug("query : '{}'", query);

      SQLQuery results = session.createSQLQuery(query);
      List list = null;
      if (null != results) {
        list = results.list();
      }
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      return list;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
      logger.error("find all failed", re);
      throw re;
    }
  }
```

Why does `results` is null ? But the SQL Query in SQLDEVELOPER returns 50 results...

This

```
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public List<?> getAllPropertyValues(String property) {
    logger.debug("finding all {} from TABLE", property);
    try {

// Set the session ...

      String query = String.format("SELECT DISTINCT t.id.%s, t.id.col2 FROM Table t ORDER BY t.id.col2", property.toLowerCase());
      logger.debug("query : '{}'", query);

      Query results = session.createQuery(query); // query is NOT NATIVE SQL here, THIS IS HQL
      List list = null;
      if (null != results) {
        list = results.list();
      }
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      return list;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
      logger.error("find all failed", re);
      throw re;
    }
  }
```

resolve the problem. But **this is not native SQL**. I'm curious to know why native SQL do not work here ?

Can someone explain why ? And how can I use native SQL here ?

Comment: I must use [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) not SQL

Comment: Try - SELECT DISTINCT s.col1, s.col2 FROM table s ORDER BY s.col2

Comment: Can you provide more code? Are you sure you have connection with db?

Comment: @wawek Connection is so fine !

Comment: Well I wanna ensure as well that you know that in this line you presented you only created query and to get result you have to execute that. Is that clear for you?

Comment: @wawek How to "execute" ? Does my code "execute" the query ?

Comment: Why is `String query = String.format("SELECT...` not native SQL? What else should it be`?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig I have tried to use native SQL... in this case I would prefer to but it does not work so I have tried a workaround, with HQL so.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig The statement that resolve the problem is not native... as I wrote it.

Comment: It is the absolutely same statement. You only changed some names of your columns. How does your schema look like?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig It is the same query but one in HQL and one in SQL. Do you understand that the question is why does native SQL do not run correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My table has no primary key, so Hibernate seems to have confusion between SQL and HQL query.

When I was retro ingeneering my database, Hibernate generate 2 classes per table.

1. `public class Classe`, representing table CLASSE
2. `public class ClasseId`, representing a embeded id on all colunms.

It is odd to me but I think each classe representing a table has to have an id.